# make my project including sql server database and crystal report as a setup exe

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I make a project using visual studio 2010 (C# windows application), sql server 2008 and sap crystal report the last edition.

I finished my project and i want to give it to the user to use it the user have a machine with operating system windows xp.

Ho can i install my application on end user machine ?

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

for your database it depends on your project and how you wrote it.but to include sql server and crystal report you can use setup factory.
download it from [here](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Authoring-tools/Setup-creators/Setup-Factory.shtml)